# Doing a wildcard search in a ps query and running into

Tags: sql

I'm searching a table entry for commas, and if found, I want to wrap the field in double quotes.

Below is the code I'm trying to run (but failing)

```
CASE WHEN E.BOR_JOB_TITLE LIKE '%,%'
TO_CHAR('''''' || E.BOR_JOB_TITLE || '''''')
ELSE E.BOR_JOB_TITLE
END
```

I can't reference a "from" statement in the expression, and the syntax of this one is bad.  How would I code this?

Comment: What is a "ps query"?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Why are you using `to_char()` on a string?

Answer (score 0):

I can smell that this is oracle and you are missing `THEN`. Use the query like this:

```
Select
CASE WHEN E.BOR_JOB_TITLE LIKE '%,%'
     THEN '"' || E.BOR_JOB_TITLE || '"'
     ELSE E.BOR_JOB_TITLE
END as job_title
FROM your_table t
```